# wpa_supplicant not connecting at boot but manually

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, wpa-supplicant, yocto-project

I generated an embedded Linux system with Yocto Kirkstone, which has all the required modules for WiFi over an RTL8192 dongle.
When I start the device, wpa_supplicant fails connecting the network with the following output

```
Configuring network interfaces... 
[    5.522312] random: wpa_supplicant: uninitialized urandom read (4096 bytes read)
Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
[    5.749164] rtl8192cu: MAC auto ON okay!
[    5.785079] rtl8192cu: Tx queue select: 0x05
ioctl[SIOCSIWPMKSA]: Inappropriate ioctl for device
ioctl[SIOCSIWMODE]: Inappropriate ioctl for device
ioctl[SIOCGIWRANGE]: Inappropriate ioctl for device
ioctl[SIOCGIWMODE]: Inappropriate ioctl for device
ioctl[SIOCSIWAP]: Inappropriate ioctl for device
ioctl[SIOCSIWESSID]: Inappropriate ioctl for device
ioctl[SIOCSIWENCODEEXT]: Inappropriate ioctl for device
ioctl[SIOCSIWENCODEEXT]: Inappropriate ioctl for device
ioctl[SIOCSIWENCODEEXT]: Inappropriate ioctl for device
ioctl[SIOCSIWENCODEEXT]: Inappropriate ioctl for device
ioctl[SIOCSIWENCODEEXT]: Inappropriate ioctl for device
ioctl[SIOCSIWENCODEEXT]: Inappropriate ioctl for device
ioctl[SIOCSIWPMKSA]: Inappropriate ioctl for device
[    9.613212] random: crng init done
[    9.615185] random: 4 urandom warning(s) missed due to ratelimiting
udhcpc: started, v1.35.0
udhcpc: broadcasting discover
udhcpc: broadcasting discover
udhcpc: broadcasting discover
udhcpc: no lease, forking to background
```

But when I manually do

```
ip link set wlan0 up
wpa_supplicant -i wlan0 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf &
```

It connects my network and gets the IP with no issue.

What's wrong here ?
Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer.
In /etc/network/interfaces, the driver was set to `wpa-driver wext`, but it was supposed to be `wpa-driver nl80211`.